# Twilio Verification SDK not reading SMS on Android 7.0 and 8.0

Tags: android, twilio

I've been working with the Twilio Verification SDK for Android (com.twilio:verification:1.0.9) with this build.gradle configuration: compile_sdk = 26, min_sdk = 23, target_sdk = 26, and build_tools = '27.0.3' and I haven't been able to make the app to read the SMS on Android 7.0 and 8.0 devices; however, it works fine on Android 6.0.

This is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
class PhoneVerificationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        RxBus.publish(PhoneVerificationEvent(TwilioVerification.getVerificationStatus(intent).state))
    }

}
```

It's declared on AndroidManifest this way:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".service.PhoneVerificationReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.twilio.verification.current_status" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here I have the subscription:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    disposable.add(
            RxBus.listen(PhoneVerificationEvent::class.java)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({
                        when (it.state) {
                            VerificationStatus.State.STARTED, VerificationStatus.State.AWAITING_VERIFICATION -> {
                                lockUI()
                            }
                            VerificationStatus.State.SUCCESS -> {
                                savePhoneNumber()
                            }
                            VerificationStatus.State.ERROR -> {
                                unlockUI("Phone couldn\'t be verified")
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        Timber.e(it)
                    })
    )
}

override fun onPause() {
    disposable.clear()
    super.onPause()
}
```

After retrieving the JWT token, the verification process starts, it successfuly enters the `onReceive` method with `VerificationStatus.State.STARTED`. After that, the SMS is received but it's not entering the `onReceive` function anymore.

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkTv6.png)

The Android SDK Hash Signature is in place; I followed this tutorial: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/tutorials/android-sdk-register-your-app; this code works fine on Android 6.0 devices.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am not an Android developer, but I checked with the team internally for help and here's what they told me.

Manifest declared broadcast receivers have some restrictions on newer versions of Android. Can you register the broadcast receiver at runtime using `context.registerReceiver` and unregister using `context.unregisterReceiver`.

There's more info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Tried context-registering/unregistering the broadcast receiver and it's still not reading the SMS. It seems like the receiver is not catching external intents because after starting the verification with Twilio, I receive the STARTED state from the intent.

Comment: Are you sure that PhoneVerificationReceiver is not receiving more updates?, cause it might be an issue with RxBus.publish

Comment: Yes, it's not receiving updates, I added a breakpoint on the `onReceive` method and it only enters once with the STARTED state; then, the SMS arrives but it doesn't enter `onReceive` again.